# Propositional Logic: Natural Deduction using Elimination and Introduction rules

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

So, we have to prove ⇁Y as conclusion from premises:
A. (X ∨ Y) ⇒ (X ∧ Y)
B. ⇁X

What I’ve tried so far is basically:

1. ⇁X  [Premise]
2. ⇁X ∨ (X ∧ Y)     [∨In, 1]
3. (X ∨ Y) ⇒ (X ∧ Y)    [Premise]

.

.

.

n. X ∧ Y     [⇒ Out]

(n+1). X     [ ∧ Out, n]

(n+2). ⇁X  [Reiteration from 1]

(n+3). Y [ ∧ Out, n]

(n + 4): Y ⇒ (X ∧ ⇁X)

(n + 5): ⇁ Y  [⇁In from (n+4)]

To prove (n+4):
We assume Y then reiterate X and ⇁X we obtained from (n+1) and 1. respectively. So, thus we deduced X and ⇁X from assumption Y thus using [⇒In] to prove (n+4):

Stuck at obtaining line n. For using ⇒Out we have lines 3.(of form A ⇒C), 2 (of form A ∨ B)
We need just (of form B ⇒ C) i.e. ⇁X ⇒ (X ∧ Y) to complete the proof.
So, using Introduction and Elimination rules for ∧, ∨, ⇒, ⇁, etc. and similar formal proof rules how do we derive ⇁X ⇒ (X ∧ Y) in context of above question and proof?

Comment: Is "⇁" meant to be negation?

Comment: Assume $Y$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, tried that. But for deriving a contradiction we need X ^ ⇁X using [^ In] rules.(Yes, ⇁ means a negation).
 But for that we need X and ⇁X derived from somewhere. We have negation of X as a premise. But I'm not able to get obtain X by any means.

Comment: From $Y$ derive $X \land Y$ by $(\lor \text I)$ folowed by $(\to \text E)$. Then $X$ by $(\land \text E)$ and finally $(X \land \lnot X)$ by $(\land \text I)$. That's all

Comment: I might be wrong here but I think we can't derive X∧Y by (∨I). We need (∧I) to derive X∧Y. And for ∧I we need, X and Y as seperate (we don't have X even if we assume Y).

Comment: @TenO'Four, Yes ⇁ is a negation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Derivation

$\begin{array}{}
\{1\}&1.&\lnot X&\text{P}\\
\{2\}&2.&(X\lor Y)\to(X\land Y)&\text{P}\\
\{3\}&3.&Y&\text{A for RAA}\\
\{3\}&4.&X\lor Y&\text{3, $\lor$I}\\
\{2,3\}&5.&X\land Y&\text{2, 4, MP}\\
\{2,3\}&6.&X&\text{5, $\land$E}\\
\{1,2,3\}&7.&\bot&\text{1, 6, $\bot$I}\\
\{1,2\}&8.&\lnot Y&\text{3, 7, RAA}\\
\end{array}$

Comment: Hey! I'm not as used to all the rules in formal logic since I'm just beginning with logic. So, could you please explain line number 3 (How is Y concluded via RAA) and how does line 7 become a contradiction (is it because we arrive both at X and ⇁X?) ?

Comment: On line 3, we're assuming Y for the purposes of applying RAA later on. Basically, "if Y then we arrive at a contradiction, thus Y must be false". Line 7, we're conjoining 1, which is $\lnot X$ and 6, which is X